# No puedo abrir PDF, adjunto con PHP mail

Tags: php

Envío mail con PHP (5.3.29 indica mi proveedor) con archivo PDF adjunto. EL mail me llega correctamente, pero cuando quiero abrir el archivo PDF en mi computadora (Gmail y Adobe en mi computadora, o Gmail y lector de PDF de Drive en mi móvil), me aparecen mensajes de error y de formato no válido respectivamente.

Les agradecería si me pueden ayudar, hace días que estoy con esto y no logro encontrar la falla en mi código, gracias !

```
<?php
$name           = "william";
$email      = "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
//$to             = "$name <$email>";
$to = "$email";
$from           = "AAA";
$subject        = "some text";
$mainMessage    = "Hi, here's the file.";
$fileatt        = "myfile.pdf";
$fileatttype    = "application/pdf";
$fileattname    = "newname.pdf";
$headers        = "From: $from";
// File
$file           = fopen ( $fileatt, 'rb' );
$data           = fread ( $file, filesize ( $fileatt ) );
fclose ( $file );
// Attach the file
$semi_rand  = md5 ( time () );
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers       .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
$message        = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "-{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $mainMessage . "\n\n";
$data           = chunk_split ( base64_encode ( $data ) );
$message      .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n" . " name=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" . "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n" . "-{$mime_boundary}-\n";
// Send Email
if (mail ( $to, $subject, $message, $headers )) {   
    echo "The email was sent!";
} else {    
    echo "There was an error sending the mail.";
}
?>
```

[[image: compu][1]]

Comment: No me gusta la idea pero, ¿podrías incluir una captura de lo que sale en el compu cuando intentas abrirlo, por favor?

Comment: Esa es la compu, el archivo está en el path correcto, y existe. Cuando intento ver el adjunto, me pide descargarlo porque tiene formato desconocido. Luego de descargado, sale este mensaje, muchas gracias !

Comment: Probé con la libreria AttachMailer y sucede exactamente lo mismo, aunque con código diferente.

Comment: Y el archivo que adjuntas, antes de adjuntarlo... se puede abrir?? Lo otro: le estás pasando el filesize de `$fileatt` pero no es una ruta absoluta, así que no sabemos si está pasando el valor correcto. ¿Podrías hacer debug de esos valores, atributos del archivo para saber si llevan lo que esperas? En [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) el ejemplo tiene una ruta absoluta al archivo, así que tu ejemplo sólo adjuntaría el archivo si está en la ruta base de la ejecución del script PHP

Comment: anduvo perfecto! hice debug con errores, y la diferencia era en la extensión. Parece mentira, está generado como PDF y no es lo mismo que pdf. Puede ser esto así ? Muchísimas gracias! me has orientado perfectamente

Comment: Me alegra mucho! Recuerda poner la solución como respuesta (puedes incluso marcarla como aceptada unas horas después!). Así los demás tendrán esto en cuenta. Y sí, el nombre de archivo suele ser case-sensitive incluyendo la extensión. :)

Comment: me indicas por favor cómo lo hago ?

Comment: Abajo hay un recuadro Tu respuesta. Pon la respuesta ahí